# Auto Increment PHP foreach loop with conditional statements

Tags: php, foreach, conditional-statements, auto-increment

I created a `foreach` loop that loops through ~50 field values. I'm using conditional statements to output only the fields I want. I want to style alternating rows differently (and I have to use inline css since this is for an HTML email). I assume I can achieve this by iterating through the loop using the `$i` variable and then get odd/even numbers. The problem I'm getting is that this loop is iterating through ~50 fields and since I am not outputting some fields, the integer is not in order. The result is 1,2,3,7,10,etc. I can't get an accurate odd/even result with this result.

Here is the code:

```
$i = 1;
foreach ( $form['fields'] as $field ) {
    $use_text = false;

    $raw_field_value = RGFormsModel::get_lead_field_value( $entry, $field );
    $field_value = GFCommon::get_lead_field_display( $field, $raw_field_value, rgar( $entry, 'currency' ), $use_text, $format, 'email' );

    if ( $field->type == "product" || $field->type == "hidden" || $field->type == "section" || $field->type == "html" ) {
        continue;
    } else if ( GFFormsModel::is_field_hidden( $form, $field, array(), $entry ) ) {
        // ignore fields hidden by conditional logic
        continue;
    }

    if ( $field_value === false ) {
        continue;
    }

    if ( !empty( $field_value ) || strlen( $field_value ) > 0 ) {
        $message .= '<tr style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; padding: 0;" align="left">';

            $message .= '<td style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: none; -moz-hyphens: none; hyphens: none; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; color: #252b23; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; border-left-style: solid; border-left-color: #ccc; border-left-width: 1px; border-top-color: #ccc; border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; margin: 0; padding: 8px;" align="left" valign="top"><strong>' . $field->label . '</strong> ' . $i . '</td>';
            $message .= '<td style="word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: none; -moz-hyphens: none; hyphens: none; border-collapse: collapse !important; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; color: #252b23; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; border-left-style: solid; border-left-color: #ccc; border-left-width: 1px; border-top-color: #ccc; border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; margin: 0; padding: 8px;" align="left" valign="top">' . $field_value . '</td>';

        $message .= '</tr>';
    }

    $i++;
}
```

Is there a way to change the integer results to be based on the final result that is output? If only 5 fields are output, the integer values should be 1,2,3,4,5.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Why not put the `$i++` inside your `if` statement?

Comment: only increment $i where you are not ignoring fields, that way it will be consistent with what you expect

Comment: @andrewsi that worked! I wasn't aware the increment was affected by an `if` statement. I thought it was only affected by the overall foreach loop. Thanks!

Comment: if *$forms* is a non-associative array, you can get your *$i* this way: `foreach ( $form['fields'] as $i => $field ) {`. Then you don't have to increment it at all.

Comment: @andrewsi I think I gave you an up-vote, but how can I attribute your comment as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

By the use of `continue`, you skip the rest of the `foreach` body, including the increment of the *$i* variable.

To avoid this, you could do the increment at the start of the iteration, and initialise *$i* at 0:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ( $form['fields'] as $field ) {
    $i++;
```

If *$forms* is a plain array -- with numerical indexes -- then you can write the above three lines like this:

```
foreach ( $form['fields'] as $i => $field ) {
```